# What happens if Javascript template strings aren't supported in a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

If I have some JS code and do this :

```
var string = `fred's string`;
```

What happens if template strings isn't supported by the current browser? Does it fail gracefully or will this error out?

Comment: It throws a `TypeError`...

Comment: How can I support strings that may contain either " or ' ?  I'm injecting it in the JS of a pug template

Comment: Check out the dupe and the second answer... That should be the way.

Comment: Thanks that should work